# How can I use my local iis and mvc to work together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have started a new mvc project and clicked on project\properties\web - use local IIS server (mine is 5.1).  I've created a virtual directory all ok.

When I run I get a 403 error - in url http://localhost/myProjectName/

I have set IIS to windows integrated security and set web.config to windows.

My ultimate goal is to use mixed windows and forms authentication for an intranet app.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you restarted IIS since changing mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this will work off the bat for IIS 5.1.  By default, MVC controllers/pages don't have extensions, and so IIS doesn't know who to forward the request to during the request pipeline.

In IIS 6.0, you can set a IIS wildcard mapping forward all unknown files to the ASP.NET engine.  For 5.1, you'll probably have to configure MapRoutes so that your urls include the mvc extension:

```
http://localhost/myproject/home.mvc
```

Comment: Thanks - I changed the routing in mvc to look for that - how do I do configure IIS?

Comment: Within the Virtual Directory tab of the properties for the site, click on the Configuration button.

In Application Mappings, click the Add button.  Locate the aspnet_isapi.dll in \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727.  Just make sure All Verbs is selected but that Check that file exists is not.

Comment: Davy, have you had any success with this approach?

Comment: I can get the app to load but as soon as i click on another action it just reloads that page and drops all styling.

Comment: Check the links on the page, and ensure that they're going where you expect them to (e.g, they have the mvc extension).  Are you using Html.Action?

Comment: Sorry should add - http://localhost/myProject/ is fine.

if I change my route code to:

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "default.aspx/{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = "" }
              );

This is based on what I read here: http://www.asp.net/LEARN/mvc/tutorial-08-cs.aspx

Now - http://localhost/FirstMVC/default.aspx/Order.mvc returns

the output from http://localhost/myProject but with no styling.

Comment: Should your URL be localhost/myProject/Order.mvc instead of localhost/FirstMVC/default.aspx/Order.mvc?

Comment: sorry typo - It's working now.  I'm not sure exactly what I had done wrong but the advice here was sound - thanks.

Now I have - http://localhost/myProject/Home.mvc/About etc working with route code.

routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = "" }
              );

So in conclusion - Add .mv mapping extention and change routing as above.

Thanks again.

Davy

Comment: Ok, going forward: 

IIS 5.1 needs some extension to help the service route requests
IIS 6.0 needs either an extension or wildcard mapping
IIS 7.0 handles MVC requests out-of-the-box

Glad to hear all of this helped.

Answer (score 0):

It can work. Solution is not elegant but it does exist.
Take a look at my article [IIS vs. ASP.NET URL Rewriting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/iis-aspnet-url-rewriting.aspx)